# How to remove the vertical line on VS CODE

Tags: visual-studio-code

I went into the settings.json, but the `"editor.rulers":[]` array is already empty. I still have the line in the middle. Please advise step by step to remove this. Thank you in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You appear to be looking at the *default* settings JSON (not your actual settings JSON), which should contain nothing in that array (did you reach this via the command palette)?

Try the following:

1. Open the settings menu by clicking the Gear icon in the bottom left and selecting Settings, or by the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>.
2. In the top right of the settings menu, click the ellipsis in the top right and select "Show modified settings."

[image: show modified settings]

3. See if the "Editors: Rulers" setting is in your list of settings after filtering on modified settings. If it is, click the "Edit in settings.json" link for it, and delete the setting from your JSON.

[image: editor: Rulers]